# Matrix to string in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have an m*6 matrix in matlab and I want to display it in a string without the whitespace and the semicolons. I used the mat2str function but the output would e like that [1 2 3; 4 5 6; ...] . Is there any function or effecient way to prduce a string with no whitespace and semicolons ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: I doubt there is library code to do this. You are going to have to write something to loop over every row, every column and print out the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = sprintf('%d', mtx);
```

Comment: thnx Oli, is there any specific reason for choosing %d ?

Comment: @Momo: Only that the values in your example appeared to all be integers.  Take a look at the format specifiers in the manual (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html), and experiment to find what works best for you.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: maybe you should add a space `'%d '` so that the different numbers are actually separated?